# how to set environment variable in lumber framework?

Tags: javascript, npm, forestadmin

**Install Lumber**

```
npm install -g lumber-cli -s
```

then,

```
 lumber generate "adminpanel_test" --connection-url "mysql://root@localhost:3306/admin-dev" --ssl "false" --application-host "localhost" --application-port "3310"
```

**lumber is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Answer (score 0):

lumber-cli is not installed properly on your shell.

If you run this you can see the reason why it is stop installing.

```
npm install -g lumber-cli
```

Sometimes it can work if you are working on local env.

```
sudo npm install -g lumber-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to install it locally:

```
$ npm install —save-dev lumber-cli
```